# How do I install a specific version of Docker on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Docker 1.4 seems to have broken the way that Fig mounts volumes within it. I'm trying to figure out how to rollback to version 1.3 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to accomplish this via

```
sudo apt-get install lxc-docker-1.3.3
```