# Installing a specific version of docker-engine (v1.7+) on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Docker have changed the way `docker-engine` is installed on Ubuntu since version 1.7 (if I'm not mistaken). Before you could do for example:

```
sudo apt-get install lxc-docker-1.3.3
```

to install version `1.3.3` as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27463257/398441) answer. But nowadays the [installation instructions](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#installation) tells us to do:

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

But this always installs (or upgrades to) the lastest version of Docker. This is not always what you want to do, for example when managing a cluster of servers which needs to run a specific Docker version. So my question is, how do I install a specific version with all required dependencies?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/472412/how-do-i-upgrade-docker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is to add extra command after your `curl` command

```
# apt-get install docker-engine=1.7.1-0~trusty
```

More detail explaination:

`docker-engine` is used instead of `lxc-docker` since 1.7.x as you noticed.

The command you used `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh` is a shortcut to install latest version, and it works for all the platform

If you use ubuntu, you can check detail steps inside https://get.docker.com, it is like below:

```
# apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
# echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main " >   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
# apt-get update 
# apt-get install docker-engine
```

If you want to specific version, replace last step to

```
# apt-get install docker-engine=1.7.1-0~trusty
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install docker from binaries by getting it from following urls:

```
https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/i386/docker-<version> 
https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-<version>
```

Here is [ref](https://docs.docker.com/installation/binaries/) for installing from binaries.